# How to combine two observables to create new observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic4

I have two services named 'PatientsService' and 'AppointmentService'. In third service 'AppointedPatientsService', I want to subscribe to AppointmentService to get all booked appointments with patientId and after that I want to repeatedly subscribe to PatientsService.getPatient(patientId) to get Patient's data with patientId. And then, I want to return new array named allAppointedPatients which holds all appointments with patient's data. I tried this...

```
 getAppointments() {
let allAppointments: Appointment[] = [];
const allAppointedPatients: AppointedPatient[] = [];

return this.appointmentService.fetchAllAppointments().pipe(
  take(1),
  tap(appointments => {
  allAppointments = appointments;

  for (const appointment of allAppointments) {
    this.patientsService.getPatient(appointment.patientId).pipe(
      tap(patient => {
        const newAppointment = new AppointedPatient(patient.firstName,
                                                  patient.lastName,
                                                  patient.address,
                                                  patient.casePaperNumber,

 appointment.appointmentDateTime);
        allAppointedPatients.push(newAppointment);
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }
  return allAppointedPatients;
}),
pipe(tap((data) => {
  return this.allAppointedPatients;
}))
);
```

}

This is not working and I know there must be better way to handle such scenario. Please help...

Comment: where did you initialize your array?

Comment: look for rxjs's switchMap operator

Comment: @Ramesh - initializing array just before return statement.. see updated code snap

Comment: @enno.void - I tried using switch map. But I am confused as on which observable I should use switchMap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are messing up the async code (observables) with sync code by trying to return the `allAppointedPatients` array synchronously.

Understand first how async code is working in Javascript and also why Observables (streams) are so useful.

Try the code below and make sure you understand. Of course, I was not able to test it so make your own changes if needed.

```
getAppointments(): Observable<AppointedPatient[]> {
    return this.appointmentService.fetchAllAppointments()
        .pipe(
            switchMap(appointments => {

                const pacientAppointments = [];

                for (const appointment of allAppointments) {

                    // Extract the data aggregation outside or create custom operator
                    const pacientApp$ = this.patientsService.getPatient(appointment.patientId)
                        .pipe(
                            switchMap((pacient) => of(
                                new AppointedPatient(
                                    patient.firstName,
                                    patient.lastName,
                                    patient.address,
                                    patient.casePaperNumber,
                                    appointment.appointmentDateTime
                                )
                            ))
                        )

                    pacientAppoinments.push(pacientApp$);
                }

                return forkJoin(pacientAppointments);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help! Its working perfectly, though I am still understanding the code

Comment: How to define return type for this getAppointments() function? Because when I am subscribing to it, I am not able to assign it to appointedPatients..

Comment: I edited with the return type, but you can also use "any" when you are really not sure.

Comment: The above code is not working with AngularFire (realtime database). I only updated patients and appointment services using AngularFire (previously it was by using HttpClient)

Comment: @PrashantGujar because `forkJoin` is waiting for the Observable to complete. In a "realtime database", the observables are probably not completing but keep pushing data. Try the `merge` operator instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use forkJoin:

```
forkJoin(
            getSingleValueObservable(),
            getDelayedValueObservable()
            // getMultiValueObservable(), forkJoin on works for observables that complete
          ).pipe(
            map(([first, second]) => {
              // forkJoin returns an array of values, here we map those values to an object
              return { first, second };
            })
          );
```